# How do I get error from server when I make a request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am making a request to the server and if I get an error, I want to console.log it but returns a javascript error instead.

I found this solution online where in my interception I can return the error appropriately but seem not to work.

```
   Axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    function(error) {
        // Do something with response error
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            console.log("unauthorized, logging out ...");
            store.commit("logout");
            router.push({ path: "/login" });
        }
        return Promise.reject(error.response);
    }
  );
```

This is my request:

```
  Axios.put("/api/auth/request/phone/verify", {
    phone: this.registeredPhone,
    code: this.stashedCode()
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data.status == 200 && response.data.success) {
        swal("Success", response.data.data.message, "success");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(error);
      console.log(error.response);
    });
```

Am expecting something like:

```
{
 "status": 422,
 "success": false,
 "data": {
 "erro": "validation.phone_field_required."
}
```

but I end up getting: `PUT http://localhost:3000/api/auth/request/phone/verify 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: It will most likely be because the server isn't returning the error as JSON with the detail you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in [Axios Documents](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors). you should pass valid status code as option to axios. if you dont do that the status code **4XX** is an error so it handle by catch block.

```
axios.get('/user/12345', {
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status < 500; // Reject only if the status code is greater than or equal to 500
  }
})
```

so your request wil be change like this:

```
axios({
      method: 'put',
      url: '/api/auth/request/phone/verify',
      data: {
        phone: this.registeredPhone,
        code: this.stashedCode()
      },
      validateStatus: (status) => {
        return status < 500;
      },
    }).catch(error => {

    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.status == 200 && response.data.success) {
          swal("Success", response.data.data.message, "success");
         }
    })
```

feel free to ask more question in comments

Comment: But can I now handle my error in the `.catch` block?

Comment: sure. this option only says that status codes under 500 aren't error. but if status code is >= 500 or any error like timeout, network error and ... occurs, it handled by catch block.